# SQL join two tables with different number of rows and copy the results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let me start of by saying that as I don't know how to search for this problem, this question might also be a duplicate.

Here is the situation:

I have the following two tables:

```
Language:

 - LanguageID 
 - Name
```

and

```
Product:

 - ProductID
 - LanguageID
 - Name
```

The table `Language` contains 4 records for four languages : English, French, Italian, Spanish.

The table 'Product' contains 1 record - for a product with a Name **"TEST"** in English.
I would like to do a select on those two tables that will return for every record in the `Language` table the same product record from the `Product` table.

So,

```
LanguageID, Name ,  ProductID, ProductName

1           English 1          Test

2           Italian 1          Test
```

and so on.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to match every row from the first table with every row from the second table without condition? Sounds like a cross join.

Comment: Have you tried any JOIN queries? What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  l.LanguageId,
  l.Name,
  p.ProductId,
  p.Name AS ProductName
FROM Language l
CROSS JOIN Product p
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want a cartesian product, right?

```
SELECT l.LanguageID, l.Name, p.ProductID, p.ProductName from Language l, Product p
```

This will give you every possible combination of Product and Language

Comment: i also don't know if i understood his question correctly but i think he does not mean cross join, because in the result given above, there are only two records instead of four since there are four languages.

Comment: Yeah, but there is this "and so on." below the results. I assumed he just didn't want to write the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    Language.LanguageID,
    Language.Name,
    Product.LanguageID,
    Product.Name
FROM
    Product INNER JOIN Language ON
        Product.LanguageID = Language.LanguageID
WHERE Product.Name = 'TEST'
```